# How to control deep linking?

Tags: java, android, deep-linking

I want to add a deep link in to my app, that opens the native app when the link is clicked. I used Google firebase to implement it. I copied the necessary parts for it and pasted them into my Code. But I dont know how to Control the deeplink. Additionally to that, there is an error in the Code sample from Google, what I can't believe. I searched a lot to solve this Problem, but I coul'nt find something useful.

I added this into my manifest file:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data
        android:host="example.com"
        android:scheme="https"/>
</intent-filter>
```

And I created the variable in my main activity:

```
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
```

And added this Code snipped to my main activity:

[image]

There you can see also the two Errors which I don't understand.
Also, there is the part, where I can handle the link. Unfortunately I don't know how to do it.

Sorry, but I'am new on Android Studio. I Need a Little bit time to understand the stuff :)

Comment: I can't see the errors you're receiving, can you add them to your post?

Comment: They are marked on the Screenshot. Take a look to ".enableAutoManage(this,this)" -> second line. And take a look to the else part, of the if-function

Comment: For the first error GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener should be implemented by the activity of fragmentactvitiy.

Comment: Isn't it the part with "private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;" ?

Comment: First problem: Just implement OnConnectionFailedListener in your activity.